# How to assign both Watermark and a custom property to a TextBox's Text property? (MahApps)

Tags: c#, wpf, watermark, attached-properties, mahapps.metro

I'm having problems with creating a suitable watermark in my TextBox.

I use MahApps in my project, and as long as I don't bind 'Text' to my custom property, all works fine.

But I need to trace the changes in the TextBox, and so I bind the Text property like this:

```
<TextBox controls:TextboxHelper.Watermark="Enter text here..." Text="{Binding Path=MyProperty}" />
```

In this case, the watermark property stops working, the watermark text doesn't disappear when I start typing.

How can it be helped?
Thanks!

**UPDATE** Here's the window of the sample made by [har07](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2998271/har07). 
In the lower unbound TextBox the watermark works as expected. However, when I try to type smth in the first TextBox, the watermark is still there.
[image]

**UPDATE2** Just in case someone will make the same mistake - appeared I was indeed setting my property in code while initializing the window, and that was the reason the watermark wasn't working. Now, thanks to har07, all is fine.

Comment: There shouldn't be any problem setting watermark along with `Text` binding. Works fine for me, watermark text dimmed on textbox get focus

Comment: @har07 Thanks for your reply! Could you please post your example of code? Strange it's not working with me, maybe some bug..

Comment: posted example code, with link to download sample project (VS 2012)

Comment: @har07 Thanks a lot for taking time and uploading the project! However, it doesn't work with me how expected. I made a printscreen and added to my question, from it should be seen that I can't type in the text into the bound TextBox, the watermark doesn't disappear.

Comment: okay, "Default Name" text is from `Text` property, not the watermark. Delete all text from the bound textbox, then you'll see the watermark > Move focus to not-bound textbox, then watermark in the bound textbox will get dimmed. Isn't that the expected behavior?

Comment: @har07 Oh, now it works indeed, feel myself stupid! Weird that it doesn't work with me still.. Will have to look into it further. Thanks a lot for your help, I will still mark your reply as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in comment, there shouldn't be any problem setting watermark along with `Text` binding. I made simple test using 2 textboxes, one with `Text` property bound and the other not bound. Both are showing same behavior : *watermark text replaced by typed text, and get dimmed upon textbox lost focus*.

```
//View
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="WpfMahApps.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfMahApps"
        Title="StackOverflow" Height="500" Width="625"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.DataContext>
            <local:Person/>
        </Grid.DataContext>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" Controls:TextboxHelper.Watermark="Enter text here...."/>
            <TextBox Controls:TextboxHelper.Watermark="Enter text here too...."/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Controls:MetroWindow>

//Model (I'm using MvvmLight for implementation of INPC)
public class Person : ObservableObject
{
    private string _name = "Default Name";
    public String Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Name);
        }
    }
}
```

### [Download test project](http://1drv.ms/1ePZeAv)

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking time and uploading the project! However, it doesn't work with me how expected. I made a printscreen and added to my question, from it should be seen that I can't type in the text into the bound TextBox, the watermark doesn't disappear.